# Не нажимается ссылка после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation

Форма отправляется успешно. Success отрабатывает,страница перезагружается, но нужно,чтобы после перезагрузки страницы нажалась ссылка.
Пробовал два варианта:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').validate({
    .....
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit(
          ....
          success(function(data){
            ......
            setTimeout(location.reload(),1000);
            $('#link').trigger('click');
           });
        );
      }
  });
});
```

И второй

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').validate({
    .....
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit(
          ....
          success(function(data){
            ......
            setTimeout(location.reload(),1000);
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#link').trigger('click');
            });
           });
        );
     }
  });
});
```

Ни один не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> после перезагрузки страницы нажалась ссылка

Во-первых, выражение

```
setTimeout(location.reload(),1000);
```

бессмысленно, так как `location.reload()` вызывается сразу и ничего не возвращает, так что `setTimeout` через секунду [не]вызовет `undefined`, и проку от `setTimeout` никакого нет.

Во-вторых, если предположить, что Вы хотели написать

```
setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},1000);
$('#link').trigger('click');
```

то `$('#link').trigger('click');` вызывается раньше, чем `location.reload()`. Если уж следовать Вашей логике, то надо поменять их местами.

И в-третьих, после **перезагрузки** страницы в ней может выполниться только код, который в ней (в новой странице) и вызван.

```
  success(function(data){
    ......
    localStorage.setItem("clickOnLink", "1");
    location.reload();




<script>  
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var item = localStorage.getItem("clickOnLink");
    localStorage.removeItem("clickOnLink");
    if (item == "1")
      $('#link').trigger('click');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Мне нужно нажать ссылку после перезагрузки, а не до нее

Answer (score 0):

Он не заработает так как у вас в обоих кодах указано

> setTimeout(location.reload(),1000);
>
> это перезагружает страницу

а после перезагрузки страницы, вы пытаетесь нажать на клавишу

> $('#link').trigger('click');

предлагаю подключить cookies

```
function setCookie(name, value) {
    var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60000);
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; path=/" + url_alias + "; expires=" + date.toUTCString()
}


  $(document).ready(function(){
 $('form').validate({
  .....
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit(
      ....
      success(function(data){
        ......
         setCookie('click', '1');
         setTimeout(function() {location.reload()}, 1000);
       });
       );
       }
       });
       });
```

И дальше после перезагрузки страницы сравниваем значение cookie

```
<? 
if($_COOKIE['click'] == '1'){
?>
<script> 
window.onload = function() { 
$('#link').trigger('click');
} 
</script>
<? 
}
?>
```

Comment: А нельзя сразу в функцию перезагрузки передать параметр, который бы отвечал за нажатие?